# How to move an HTML tag after an id with JavaScript without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"></div>

<div id="D"></div>
<div id="E"></div>


<div id="C"></div>`
```

How can I move `<div id="C"></div>` between id B and D  with pure javascript (without JQuery)?

Comment: There are similar questions all over the internet. I am down-voting it. Please search on google and SO before posting questions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore):

```
var C = document.getElementById("C");
var D = document.getElementById("D");
D.parentElement.insertBefore(C, D);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gogact9t/)

Comment: i neet to move the C div not create sir

Comment: @ChamindaNuwan You don't have a C div in your question, but instead of createElement just `var C = document.getElementById("C");`

Comment: omg thats my mistake How can I move <div id="C"></div> between id B and D with pure javascript (without JQuery)?